# App Profile Page are not being created

Tags: facebook, profile

I'm making some tests here and all the apps that I had created today didn't show on the App Profile Page (example http://apps.facebook.com/lojaeotica/). Is there some update or policy change for today? I didn't see anything in Developers Blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the blog posted today - http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/
Title of the topic is "Removing App Profile Pages", this would explain you on how to address your need. 
Here is what it says - "New apps will not automatically get an App Profile Page. Instead, new apps can choose to create a Facebook Page from the Dev App. Simply visit the Contact Info section in the Advanced tab of the Dev App and click on the “Create Facebook Page” button to create a new Facebook Page."

Answer (score 1):

There's an open bug report about this:https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325983410747148

Comment: As you can see, this was a change made to the platform in December 2011

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, but a poorly implemented new feature. If you only need the profile page to add it as a tab you can use this: http://www.addtab.info/

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Facebook, new apps won't get their own app page automatically. You can either create it in the apps 'advanced settings' or if you just need the link to integrate it into your facebook page, modify and use this one here:

```
www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL"
```